# How to get VS Code to prompt the user for the whole command line for debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know how to prompt for each argument separately (defining inputs in the launch/task config and then referring to them in strings in a launch/task config's `args` array property), but I want complete control over the command line arguments. VS Code passes each expanded string in `args` as a single commandline argument, so if I try to use a single `input`, it will be passed as a single argument instead of being split into multiple.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, this is not supported (unless your debug extension opts into something). See [Support expanding input parameters into multiple arguments
#83678](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678).

There was quite a bit of design discussion there, which I'd encourage you to read. Ex. [a `promptStringList` input type](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-592588285) (I personally think this was an interesting direction), [a `commandline` launch config property](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-592600592), [an `_args` property](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-624296965), [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-624936008), [this object suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-1130395198) (which I personally think was in a nice direction).

If the extension contributing debug support opts in to [`argsCanBeInterpretedByShell` for `RunInTerminalRequest`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_70.md#argscanbeinterpretedbyshell-for-runinterminalrequest), then you as the user of the extension should be able to write `args` in your launch config as a JSON string instead of an array like this: `"args": "${input:commandline}"` ([source #1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-1203282010), [source #2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-1236381454)).

That's it. That's the only way I'm aware of it being possible to get what you want without modifying how whatever program is being launched by the launch config interprets arguments (Ex. defining the program itself to take individual commandline arguments that it receives and further split them by some decided-upon delimiters before further interpreting them).

The issue ticket is closed with [this message](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-1284194403):

> with VS Code's support for uninterpreted arguments (see [comment above](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83678#issuecomment-1236381454)), we have no further plans to work on this issue.